# AC coupling in MATLAB / Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I've been trying to use Simulink for modelling an oscilloscope (including DSP). I am still very novice so please forgive me if the following question is way too easy: How do I implement AC coupling (remove DC component) in Simulink while using analog signals? I know there is a DC blocker, but it only accepts discrete signals and I want to discretize my signal later with an imperfect ADC.

I'm trying to use a MATLAB function for the AC coupling, but I cannot find a way to use the existing analog signal gained from the function declaration. Instead, all MATLAB documentary seems to want me to use an analog device on my computer (https://mathworks.com/help/daq/analog-data-acquisition.html).

Thank you for any efforts and/or suggestions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using the Matlab Function Block will work since you need to hold a state.  To simulate AC coupling, I believe that you need to create a high pass filter.  This removes DC from the signal so that the waveform is centered around zero.  The corner frequency generally needs to be very low so that there is no distortion of the waveform being measured.  You can build this without any special toolboxes.  You just need an integrator block, gain block and some summation blocks.

An example is provided below:
[image: Simulink Example]

This example applies a DC step to the waveform at 1 second.  The figure below provides the output

[image: output example]

In the upper figure (input) the offset remains, but in the lower figure (output) the offset is removed.

Comment: This is great! I tried making an analog filter, but it changed the entire characteristic of the input signal. This solution seems to not effect the amplitude at any frequency that I'm trying to use. For some frequencies it takes a little while to settle, but that's no problem. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want using the matlab **AC Coupling** function, try using the Matlab Function Block : https://fr.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/creating-an-example-model-that-uses-a-matlab-function-block.html . You can use it like any matlab function, i.e. `function [out1, out2] = my_function(in1)` but it will be defined in a simulink block.

Comment: Yeah I know how to add the function block, but I can't get the functionality right. Thanks for the help though!